# update the code in enterprise architect with reverse engineering

Tags: java, uml, enterprise-architect

I imported the source directory in EA and after that I added a class in the source code and tried to synchronize the package contents. The added class is not added in EA. Even if a class is deleted from the source code, the "synchronize the package contents" will not work. Is there any other solution. I don't want to import the source directory everytime, because it takes a lot of time and it is not practical in my case.

I am using Version 15.1.
[image]

Comment: I think it does exactly what is stated here. It synchronizes all classes in the (EA) package that have a source file. The new class in the code doesn't exist in the model, and thus is not synchronized. I'm guessing the behavior where it doesn't delete an existing class in the model if the source file isn't found, is deliberate as well.

Comment: I wouldn't give too much for EA's RE capabilities (nor on that of any other UML tool). Give it a shot to import a souce tree and polish it up manually. After that you're in the case of manually synching anyways. Having source control with EA is just a (bad) dream..

Comment: thank u. So my solution for the update of the already imported classes  is with "synchronize package contents". This option will get the new attributes and methods of the existing classes. If a new class is created, it can be added with "import source directory" (the "use timestamps" option needs to be checked)